# how to unit test the components connected to Rpi?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I had completed my project in raspberry pi and I found it working. I have to test my components and codes.I had gone through pytest but I am not sure how it gonna help me in my case. Is there any automated tools that could be useful to me or any others testing modules that comes with python?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can make a try with `pytest`, but probably you'll need to add something like looped delays or any other kinds of waits if you're going to test asynchronous components.

For example, if you have some class that operates with pins and want to verify high voltage level on button press, you could use something like this:

```
def test_reading_pin_value():
    # let's pretend you have some class to control pins
    with InOutController() as ctrl:
        ctrl.setup_pin('button', 26, mode=pi.IN, pull_down=True)
        while True:
            value = ctrl['button']
            if value == 1:
                break
            time.sleep(0.2)
```

Note that instead of `while True` you can set some reasonable limit of time and call `assert` with some condition or `pytest.fail` if timeout is reached:

```
import pytest
from time import time

def test_something_asynchronous():
    # your external components controller
    controller = Controller()
    start = time()
    wait, timeout = 10.0, False

    while not timeout:
        value = controller.wait_response()
        if value:
            assert value == 1, "Invalid response!"
            break
        elapsed = time() - start
        if elapsed >= wait:
            timeout = True

    assert not timeout, "Timeout!"
```

If your components have some additional stochasticity, you could try "probabilistic asserts" like:

```
def probabilistic_assert(condition, trials=100):
    n, ok = 0, False
    while n < trials and not ok:
        ok = condition()
        n += 1
    assert ok, "Condition has been failed during %d trials" % trials
```

Also, you could invoke `gpio` command and parse its output if you want to know  voltage levels on pins.

Anyway, I think you will probably need "manual" intervention into tests to activate your outer components or to wait periodically to fulfill test expectations if your components are activated by some external condition.